# plotting a text file with 4 columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a text file with 4 columns that first column in longitude,second in latitude, third is depth and forth is amount of displacement in each point.(it's related to a fualt)

-114.903874    41.207504     1.446784    2.323745

I want a plot to show the amount of displacement in each point (like images that we plot with imagesc),unfortunately "imagesc" command doesn't work for it.

how can I plot it?
Thanks for your attention

Comment: Your problem is unclear to me. Could you already read the content of the text file to MATLAB? How exactly do you want to plot the displacement?

Comment: yes, I import the text file to matlab with importdata command.I want to show displacement with differences in color on map(use a colorbar) can I use contour command to plot long,lat,depth  and then add forth column with other command?

Comment: You can use contour to plot long,lat,depth. But how would you like to add displacement then? The colors in contour indicate the values of z (in your case depth). You could generate a 3D-plot of long,lat,depth using plot3 and change the color of every point according to the displacement.

Comment: good idea, do you think how I can change the color of every point according to the displacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to use [scatter3](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) and assign your displacements to be the colours.  Note that you have to supply a size for this to work - I'm using `[]` (empty matrix) which will set it to default.  If your four sets of values are four vectors of the same size, then it's just something like:

```
scatter3(lat,lon,depth,[],displacement, 'filled')
```

Values in `displacement` will be linearly mapped to the current colormap.  `'filled'` gives you filled markers rather than open ones (default marker is a circle but can be changed).

Answer (score 0):

You can plot each point using `plot3(longitude,latitude,depth)`. You can color each point according to the displacement in a `for` loop. The easiest way to do this is create a colormap, e.g. using `jet` and chosing the color according to the displacement.

```
figure;
hold on;
cmap = jet(256);
dispRange = [min(displacement),max(displacement)];
for k=1:size(longitude,2)
    c = cmap(1+round(size(cmap,1)*(displacement(k)-dispRange(1))/dispRange(2)),:); 
    plot3(longitude(k),latitude(k),depth(k),'o', ...
        'MarkerEdgeColor',c,'MarkerFaceColor',c);
end
```

Comment: Dear hbaderts ,Thanks for your attention, I certainly examine what you said

Comment: This is totally the approach I would have done...until I learned of the `scatter3` command in the reply from @nkjt.  I've never used `scatter3` but it does look great.  If it doesn't work for some reason, this reply by @hbaderts is also good.